# Why can't this SimpleDateFormat parse this date string?

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

The SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat pdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSaa");
```

The exception thrown by `pdf.parse("Mar 30 2010 5:27:40:140PM");`:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mar 30 2010 5:27:40:140PM"
```

Any ideas?

---

**Edit:** thanks for the fast answers. You were all correct, I just missed that one key sentence in the SimpleDateFormat docs - I should probably call it a day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [SimpleDateFormat javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#month):

> Month: If the number of pattern
>   letters is 3 or more, the month is
>   interpreted as text; otherwise, it is
>   interpreted as a number.

Try to use pattern like "MMM dd yyyy"

Answer (score 11):

First, three-char months are to be represented by `MMM`. Second, one-two digit hours are to be represented by `h`. Third, `Mar` seems to be English, you'll need to supply a `Locale.ENGLISH`, else it won't work properly in machines with a different default locale.

The following works:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy h:mm:ss:SSSa", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(sdf.parse("Mar 30 2010 5:27:40:140PM"));
```

Result (I'm at GMT-4 w/o DST):

```
Tue Mar 30 17:27:40 BOT 2010
```

Also see the [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

*Why you called it `pdf` is beyond me, so I renamed it `sdf` ;)*

Comment: I knew that would come up! It's called `pdf` because it's my DateFormat for Parsing (String => Date); I have another Date Format for Formatting (parsed Date => String). If I only had 1 DateFormat in scope, yes, I would have called it `sdf`.

Answer (score 6):

MM stands for numeric month. Use MMM.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I am providing the modern answer. The other answers are correct, but the `SimpleDateFormat` class that you used is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead I am using java.time, the modern and superior Java date and time API.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "MMM d uuuu h:mm:ss:SSSa", Locale.ROOT);
    String dateTimeString = "Mar 30 2010 5:27:40:140PM";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output:

> 2010-03-30T17:27:40.140

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.