# Going from MM/DD/YYYY to DD-MMM-YYYY in java

Tags: java, date, date-format

Is there a method in Java that I can use to convert `MM/DD/YYYY` to `DD-MMM-YYYY`?

For example: `05/01/1999` to `01-MAY-99`

Comment: Note that your pattern syntax is in fact invalid. It's `y` for years and `d` for day of month. The `Y` has no meaning and `D` is day of year. You want to convert from `MM/dd/yyyy` to `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Comment: You should have the Locale.English at the options:http://stackoverflow.com/a/2603676/2114308

Answer (score 28):

Use a SimpleDateFormat to parse the date and then print it out with a SimpleDateFormat withe the desired format.

Here's some code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    Date date = format1.parse("05/01/1999");
    System.out.println(format2.format(date));
```

Output:

```
01-May-99
```

Comment: You may want to supply a `Locale` to the SDF constructor, else it will just take the platform default locale for month names, which may not be the one you want to use.

Comment: Very true, you can also set the time zone with `format1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));`

Comment: For readers coming later to this question: The `SimpleDateFormat` class is long outdated and notoriously troublesome. Don’t use it. Since 2014 we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. See [the correct answer by Md. Asaduzzaman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53246677/5772882).

Answer (score 3):

## java.time

You should use *java.time* classes with Java 8 and later. To use *java.time*, add:

```
import java.time.* ;
```

Below is an example, how you can format date.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String date = "15-Oct-2018";
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);

System.out.println(localDate); 
System.out.println(formatter.format(localDate));
```

Comment: @Billal, If you add import java.time.*; in code block. then you should also add class name definition. I just want to clarify the developers which package I am using

Comment: Yes, that is very right, I actually forgot to roll back my edit, sorry, thank you

Comment: I suggest always specifying explicitly the intended `Locale` needed for translating the name of the month. Here we would use something English related, such as `Locale.CANADA` or `Locale.US` or `Locale.UK`. Pass as the optional second argument to `ofPattern` method. The current default locale at runtime might not be English, in which case this code with this input would fail, throwing an exception.

Comment: For Java 6 & 7, must of the *java.time* functionality is available in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. So no need to ever use the terrible `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormat` classes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
Date currDate = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String strCurrDate = dateFormat.format(currDate);
System.out.println("strCurrDate->"+strCurrDate);
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println("Formatted Date: " + formatter.format(localDate));
```

Java 8 LocalDate

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); // Set your date format
String currentData = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

#### A Date-Time parsing/formatting type is `Locale`-sensitive

A Date-Time parsing/formatting type (e.g. `DateTimeFormatter`) is `Locale`-sensitive i.e. the same letters will produce the text in different `Locale`s .e.g. `MMM` is used for the three-letter abbreviation of month name and it can be different words in different `Locale`s. **In the absence of the `Locale` parameter, it will use the JVM's `Locale`**. Therefore, never forget to use a Date-Time parsing/formatting type without the `Locale` parameter. Learn more about it from [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

You need two instances of `DateTimeFormatter` - one to parse the input string and another to format the output string, as per required patterns.

#### Demo:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strDate = "05/01/1999";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dtfInput);

        // The default string i.e. the value returned by LocalDate#toString
        System.out.println(date);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutputEng = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formattedEng = dtfOutputEng.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedEng);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutputFr = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu", Locale.FRENCH);
        String formattedFr = dtfOutputFr.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedFr);
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
1999-05-01
01-May-1999
01-mai-1999
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/lzLrMD)

#### Some other important notes:

1. Instead of `Y` (*week-based-year*), you need to use `y` (*year-of-era*) and instead of `D` (*day-of-year*), you need to use `d` (*day-of-month*). Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to learn more about it.
2. Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Below should work.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date oldDate = df.parse(df.format(date)); //this date is your old date object
```

Answer (score -1):

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
```