# How to convert date of type dd.mm.yy to dd/mm/yy?

Tags: java, selenium

How can i convert date of type `dd.mm.yy` to `dd/mm/yy` ?

i'm using Selenium + Java

Thanks

Comment: You don't need Selenuim for date conversion, just read about `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`...

Comment: I tried and i found many formats but i didn't find nothing about dd.mm.yy

Comment: Why selenium is tagged ? It is job of binding language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Going from MM/DD/YYYY to DD-MMM-YYYY in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169634/going-from-mm-dd-yyyy-to-dd-mmm-yyyy-in-java)

Comment: Your usage of *type* confuses me, please use correct jargon for us to understand what you mean. The *type* is whether you've got a `String`, a modern `LocalDate` (recommended) or an outdated `Date` (not recommended). Whether your string follows dd/mm/yy or dd.mm.yy is called its *format*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `java.util.Date` :

```java
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
Date unformattedDate = dateTimeFormatter.parse("your date here");

dateTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
String formattedDate = dateTimeFormatter.format(unformattedDate);
```

**This is a legacy package and the below code is recommended**

If you are using `java.time.*`

```java
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yy");
LocalDate unformattedDate = LocalDate.parse("your date here", dateTimeFormatter);

dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy");
String formattedDate = dateTimeFormatter.format(unformattedDate);
```

And I would make the following change to your pattern. Instead of using `y` I would use `u` for the year since it also covers `AD` and `BC`.

Example: `dd/MM/uu`.

For more refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/7954021).

Comment: To all readers: Do not use the first example, it's practically legacy code. Only use it in case you are not able or allowed to use `java.time`. Second example is worth a +1, but might be improved by mentioning a difference between the pattern characters `y` and `u`.

Comment: The second code throws an exception `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '18.10.21' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {Year=2021, DayOfMonth=18, MinuteOfHour=10},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed`

Comment: @saka1029 change `mm` to `MM`. `mm` is used for minutes. `MM` is used for Months.

Comment: @deHaar thank you for your comment. What do you mean by `y` and `u`?

Comment: @Renis1235 - It is very important for you to understand what deHaar has mentioned.  Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) to learn about it.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash thank you! I updated the answer and learned something as well.