# How to get date from date time in java

Tags: java, datetime-format

This is my date string,

```
String dd = "Nov-08-2019 07:00:28.190 UTC(+0000)";
```

I want to get only date with "yyyy-MM-dd" format.
How can I get date with this format.
I tried with below code, But it's not working.

```
String dd = "Nov-08-2019 07:00:28.190 UTC(+0000)";

          Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse(dd);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
          String newstr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
           System.out.println("\n"+newstr+"\n");
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

Using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, it’s pretty simple when you know how:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "MMM-dd-uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz(xx)", Locale.ROOT);
    String dd = "Nov-08-2019 07:00:28.190 UTC(+0000)";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dd, formatter);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output is:

> 2019-11-08

As we can see, your string is in UTC. I have assumed that you also want your date in UTC. If not, we need to parse into a `ZonedDateTime`, convert to your desired zone and then format into your desired output format with only the date.

I assumed that `UTC(+0000)` is a time zone abbreviation followed by an offset in brackets.

The date and time classes that you were trying to use, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. You should not use them. java.time is so much nocer to work with.

### What went wrong in your code?

- `MM` is for two-digit month number, for example 11 for November or 08 for August. For month abbreviation like `Nov` you need `MMM`.
- `Z` is for offset like `+0000`. While this does appear in your string, the text `UTC` comes before it. Edit: Confusingly `SimpleDateFormat` parses `UTC` as time zone and then ignores the remainder of the string. I for my part shouldn’t want to rely on this behaviour.
- I recommend you specify a locale with your formatter to control which language it expects in the string. With `MMM` for month abbreviation, if you rely on the default locale and it happens to be Welsh, your formatter will expect `Tach` for November.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Related question: [Why can't this SimpleDateFormat parse this date string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603638/why-cant-this-simpledateformat-parse-this-date-string)

Comment: @Deadpool Thanks, it really depends on what `UTC(+0000)` means. I assumed (apparently like you) that it is a time zone abbreviation followed by an offset in brackets. If instead it just means that `+0000` is an offset from UTC, yours is better.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` classes those are legacy, Use java-8 modern date time API classes, First create `DateTimeFormatter` with the input format date

```
String dd = "Nov-08-2019 07:00:28.190 UTC(+0000)";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM-dd-uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz(Z)");
```

And then use `OffsetDateTime` to parse it with particular offset (In your case UTC)

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dd,formatter);
```

And then get the `LocalDate`

```
    System.out.println(dateTime.toLocalDate());
```

Comment: I believe that using `OffsetDateTime` is the safe solution as long as we don’t know for sure how times in other times zones may look (if they exist in this context at all). It will pick up the offset inside the brackets, which should be trustworthy in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you provide in the SimpleDateFormatter class constructor should match with the provided output.
e.g. since you are providing month as three letters, use 3 M's in the pattern.

```
String dd = "Nov-08-2019 07:00:28";

    Date date = null;
  try {
      date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(dd);
  } catch (ParseException e1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e1.printStackTrace();
  }
    String newstr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
     System.out.println("\n"+newstr+"\n");
}
```

Comment: The string is `Nov-08-2019 07:00:28.190 UTC(+0000)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    String dd = "Nov-08-2019 07:00:28.190 UTC(+0000)";

    Date date = null;
  try {
      date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss.S z").parse(dd);
  } catch (ParseException e1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e1.printStackTrace();
  }
    String newstr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
     System.out.println("\n"+newstr+"\n");
```

This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your input string is

```
 String dd = "Nov-08-2019 07:00:28.190 UTC(+0000)";
```

You want is

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

first it is not possible you should be getting yyyy-MMM-dd for that the code will be

```
String dd = "Nov-08-2019 07:00:28.190 UTC(+0000)";

          Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse(dd);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
          String newstr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
           System.out.println("\n"+newstr+"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

"Nov" is known as "MMM" format so it will throw the exception.
Try this code: https://onlinegdb.com/H1keFI5oS

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Main
{
     public static void main(String []args){
        String dd = "Nov-08-2019 07:00:28.190 UTC(+0000)";

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(dd);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String newstr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
        System.out.println("\n"+newstr+"\n");
     }
}
```